# Finding a vector within a vector

Tags: matlab

I have an (7,6) logical array, such as the following:

validY2_A =

```
 0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     1     0     0
 1     0     0     1     1     0
 1     1     1     0     0     1
 1     1     1     0     1     1
 0     1     1     1     1     1
```

I want to create a (1,6) logical vector 'contig' that shows whether the above matrix has 3 contiguous ones in each column. For example, the outcome of this would be:

contig =

```
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0 ,1];
```

I've tried strfind but there are two issues with this, the first being that it is an array of columns (transposing either didn't help at all. or would require lots of extra code to use temporarily. The second issue is that because it is a logical array, if I change it to a string, the values all become true or false, and trying to get that to work has also been fruitless. Is there a method to search a column vector to find if another, specific column vector exists anywhere within it? I want to search each column for [1; 1; 1];

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
t = imfilter( validY2_A, ones(3,1) );
contig = any( t >= 3, 1 );
```

Alternatively (as suggested by @Dan):

```
t = conv2( validY2_A, ones(3,1), 'same');
contig = any( t >= 3, 1 );
```

As suggested by @GeorgeAprilis, one might need to convert the logical matrix `validY2_A` to double first:

```
validY2_A = double( validY2_A );
```

Comment: +1 but should replace `imfilter` with `conv2` as might not have access to image processing toolbox

Comment: very nice approach with the `imfilter`. If `validY2_A` is a logical matrix, to work it needs to be converted to double first, otherwise `t` is also a logical matrix. When testing it I needed to change it to this:
`t = imfilter( double(validY2_A), ones(3,1) );`

Comment: Thank you so much, though can you please explain exactly what either conv2 or imfilter does? I'm looking at the matrix t and I don't understand what is happening and how the resulting calculations are made.

Comment: `conv2` applies numberical 2D convolution. Here is a worked example http://www.songho.ca/dsp/convolution/convolution2d_example.html.

Comment: Can this method be used in a columnar fashion? Your method creates the entire matrix t and the row contig in one step, though I would like to do this for each individual column in a loop.

Comment: @TheMcCleaver - WHY??? why would you want to loop? Matlab is best at vectorizing - processing matrices and vectors at single operations.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way that should be easy to understand:

```
idx1=1:end-2
idx2=2:end-1
idx3=3:end
```

Basically these indexes shift your matrix three times.

Now you just apply them:

```
any(validY2_A(idx1,:) & validY2_A(idx2,:) & validY2_A(idx3,:))
```

This is not too hard to generalize using a loop and shift function for example.